# How do I stop a gdb user defined command in the middle?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a gdb user defined command that does some setup, then might do a simple job, or a complex job. The command follows this basic structure:

```
define mycmd
  # Common setup

  if ($argc == 0)
    # Some simple thing a few lines long
    ## What goes here so I exit mycmd?
  end

  # A lot of lines doing a complex thing
end
```

Is there a C-like return I can put in place of the ## line to terminate mycmd immediately? The return, exit, quit, stop, loop_break commands don't do what I hoped for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a C-like return

There doesn't appear to be. A possible solution is to

```
define mycmd
   ... common setup
   if (condition)
     ... do simple thing
   else
     mycmd_helper
   end
end

define mycmd_helper
   ... do complex thing
end
```

Comment: I feared that was the case. Assuming somebody doesn't come in with a revelation, I'll accept your answer soon. Thanks!

Comment: @piCookie If you are using a recent version of GDB with Python scripting, a better approach might be to implement `mycmd` in Python, where you have full power of a real programming language at your disposal.

Comment: Alas, I'd switch to Python in a second, but that is not available in my GDB. Thanks though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is not its primal use, but you could use loop_break:

```
define mycmd
  # Common setup
  set $i=1
  while $i == 1
    set $i=0
    if ($argc == 0)
      # Some simple thing a few lines long
      ## What goes here so I exit mycmd?
      loop_break
    end

    # A lot of lines doing a complex thing
  end
end
```